# GetVersionEx работает неправильно

Tags: c++, windows-10

```
OSVERSIONINFOEX ovi;

  ZeroMemory(&ovi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX));
  ovi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);

  GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO*)&ovi);

  printf("dwMajorVersion = %d\n", ovi.dwMajorVersion);
```

Под Windows 10 выдаёт значение 6, хотя должно 10. Почему так?

P.S. Манифест отключил

Comment: Потому что нельзя ей пользоваться, ибо `GetVersionEx is fully deprecated in Win10`.

Comment: А чем лучше пользоваться?

Comment: Загляните в MSDN, если до сих пор этого не сделали, там всё написано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как - то так - код рабочий 100%:

```
tstring system_controll::SystemControll::getWindowsVersion()
{
    tstring versionOC;

    SYSTEM_INFO sysInfo{};

    typedef void(__stdcall *GETSYSTEMINFO) (LPSYSTEM_INFO);

    OSVERSIONINFOEX os_ver{};
    os_ver.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFOEX);

    if (!GetVersionEx((LPOSVERSIONINFO)&os_ver)) { msg_er_full; return  versionOC; }

    DWORD major{};
    DWORD minor{};

    LPBYTE pinfoRawData{};
    if (NERR_Success == NetWkstaGetInfo(NULL, 100, &pinfoRawData))
    {
        WKSTA_INFO_100* pworkstationInfo = (WKSTA_INFO_100*)pinfoRawData;
        major = pworkstationInfo->wki100_ver_major;
        minor = pworkstationInfo->wki100_ver_minor;

        os_ver.dwMajorVersion = major;
        os_ver.dwMinorVersion = minor;

        if (NERR_Success != NetApiBufferFree(pinfoRawData)) { msg_er_full; }

    }
    else if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 2)
    {
        OSVERSIONINFOEXW osvi{};
        osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osvi);
        osvi.dwMinorVersion = 3;

        ULONGLONG cm{};
        cm = VerSetConditionMask(cm, VER_MINORVERSION, VER_EQUAL);

        if (VerifyVersionInfoW(&osvi, VER_MINORVERSION, cm))
        {
            os_ver.dwMinorVersion = 3;
        }
    }

    GETSYSTEMINFO getSysInfo = (GETSYSTEMINFO)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(_T("kernel32.dll")), "GetNativeSystemInfo");
    if (getSysInfo == NULL)  getSysInfo = ::GetSystemInfo;
    getSysInfo(&sysInfo);

    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 10 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion >= 0 && os_ver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows 10 Server");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 10 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion >= 0 && os_ver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows 10");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 3 && os_ver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows Server 2012 R2");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 3 && os_ver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows 8.1");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 2 && os_ver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows Server 2012");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 2 && os_ver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows 8");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 1 && os_ver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows Server 2008 R2");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 1 && os_ver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows 7");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 0 && os_ver.wProductType != VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows Server 2008");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 6 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 0 && os_ver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION)  versionOC = _T("Windows Vista");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 2 && os_ver.wProductType == VER_NT_WORKSTATION &&  sysInfo.wProcessorArchitecture == PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64)  versionOC = _T("Windows XP x64");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 2)   versionOC = _T("Windows Server 2003");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 1)   versionOC = _T("Windows XP");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion == 5 && os_ver.dwMinorVersion == 0)   versionOC = _T("Windows 2000");
    if (os_ver.dwMajorVersion < 5)   versionOC = _T("unknown");

    if (os_ver.wServicePackMajor != 0)
    {
        tstring sp;
        TCHAR buf[128]{};
        sp = _T(" Service Pack ");

#ifdef UNICODE
        swprintf_s(buf, sizeof(buf), _T("%hd"), os_ver.wServicePackMajor);
#else
        sprintf_s(buf, sizeof(buf), _T("%hd"), os_ver.wServicePackMajor);
#endif

        sp.append(buf);
        versionOC += sp;
    }

    return versionOC;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Интересный способ через NetWkstaGetInfo! На 10-ке работает - выдаёт 10...

Comment: [Решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779419/Как-добавит-файл-манифеста-в-С-проект/795930#795930)

Answer (score 0):

MSDN [об этом сообщает английским по белому](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx):

> With the release of Windows 8.1, the behavior of the GetVersionEx API
> has changed in the value it will return for the operating system
> version. The value returned by the GetVersionEx function now depends
> on how the application is manifested.
>
> Applications not manifested for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10 will return the Windows 8 OS version value (6.2). Once an application is manifested for a given operating system version, GetVersionEx will always return the version that the application is manifested for in future releases.

---

> А чем лучше пользоваться?

И об этом он тоже сообщает на той же странице:

> To manifest your applications for Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, refer to [Targeting your application for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn481241(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: А если отключил манифест?

Comment: Targeting your application - манифест отключил. Как быть?