# Как добавит файл манифеста в С++ проект?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Искал пол дня как это сделать...
На инглише находил статейки.
Делал как там говорилось.
И не работает...
И я так и не понял как добавить этот файл манифеста в VS 2017.
Нужно это для того чтобы функция GetVersionEx/GetVersion работала корректно на Win 8.1, win 10.
Как я понял нужно прописать вот такую штуку

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">


<compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
    <application>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows Vista -->
      <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 7 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 8 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 8.1 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
      <!--The ID below indicates application support for Windows 10 -->
      <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
    </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

А как и куда я не понял.
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Properties->Configuration Properties->Manifest Tool->Additional Manifest Files

Comment: Писал туда путь к файлу... Не помогло

Comment: @Free TV, подскажите пожалуйста, Вам удалось в итоге - заставить корректно работать файл манифеста ? Такая же проблема и тупо весь день уже мучаюсь.

Answer (score 1):

1. Пишешь в блокноте следующее:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
   <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
     <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
       <security>
         <requestedPrivileges>
           <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"></requestedExecutionLevel>
         </requestedPrivileges>
       </security>
     </trustInfo>
     <dependency>
       <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity type="Win32" name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" version="6.0.0.0" publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df" language="*" processorArchitecture="*"/>
       </dependentAssembly>
     </dependency>

     <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
       <application>
         <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}"/>
         <!-- Windows 10 -->
         <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}"/>
         <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
         <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}"/>
         <!-- Windows 8 -->
         <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"/>
         <!-- Windows Vista -->
         <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"/>
         <!-- Windows 7 -->
       </application>
     </compatibility>

   </assembly>
   ```
2. Сохраняешь файл, называя "appname.exe.manifest".
3. Перетягиваешь созданный файл в Visual Studio проект - [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474237/windows-10-versionhelper-h).

Есть ещё вариант с применением [Version Helper functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn424972(v=vs.85).aspx).

Добавив заголовок `#include <VersionHelpers.h>` и написав, к примеру, таким образом:

```
if (!IsWindows10OrGreater())
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, L"OS Version: 10.0.16299", MB_OK, MB_OK);
    }
```

Comment: И на более ранних версиях Windows программа не запустится вообще, ибо статический импорт функции. Надо использовать *LoadLibrary()+GetAddressProc()* и проверять полученный указатель на *NULL* перед вызовом функции через него.

Comment: @Arhadthedev Не надо нагонять панику. Используемое в этом примере API для проверки версии доступно, начиная с Windows 2000.

Comment: Манифест как раз нужен для корректного функционирования Version Helper functions.